# Add 1 to a value and log it in the console

Tags: javascript, int

Okay so I have a var that I want to be used in a calculation(I just want to add +1 to the number inside the var) and IDK how to do it cuz when I do it the way I did in my code it won't update the var it only adds one but it won't add more so If I run the script or do it multiple times it won't add 1 to it.

```js
if(msg.content == "-testnum")
  {
    var numberino = 0;
    numberino = numberino + 1;
    msg.reply(numberino)
    console.info(numberino + 1);
  }
```

Comment: Move `var numberino = 0;` somewhere else where it’s only set once.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't understand

Comment: OK I did it, it does the same thing

Comment: please share whole js related this code part

Comment: var numberino = 0;
  if(msg.content == "-testnum")
  {
    numberino = numberino + 1;
    msg.reply(numberino)
    console.info(numberino);
  }

Comment: this is the code I have now

Comment: I can't understand what you mean. I you run `numberino + 1` twice you add 2, obviously.

Comment: @VasDávidValentin Right before the `if` is still a place where `numberino` is set to `0` every time you run the function it’s in. You need to declare `var numberino = 0;` somewhere where it’s never set to `0` again for any subsequent calls, but so that `numberino` is still in scope inside your `if`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem might be that you are running the code multiple times, so every single time you just reset your variable. However, I'm not 100% sure since its not clear if this is just a piece of the code or it is the whole code. If it is just a piece of the code however, and it is inside a loop, don't declare the variable inside the loop braces, otherwise whenever the loop runs over the variable `var numberino = 0;`, it will reset.